# Woocommerce Random Upsells

Tags: woocommerce

**Woocommerce**

Rather than adding upsells manually for each product, is there any way to display random upsell products that are within the same product category?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

Hey I came across this thread trying to figure out how to do something similar. I used most of the query given by @ViszinisA to tweek the up-sells.php template.

**up-sells.php** starting on line 23:

```
$cats = get_the_terms($product->id, 'product_cat');
if (!count($cats)) {
    return;
}
$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'no_found_rows'       => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => 5,
    'orderby'             => 'rand',
    'post__not_in'        => array( $product->id ),
    'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
    'tax_query'           => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                    'field' => 'id',
                                    'terms' => $cats[0]->term_id
                                )
                            )
);
$prodQuery = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $prodQuery->have_posts() ) {
    $postProds = $prodQuery->posts;
?>

    <section class="up-sells upsells products">

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'You may also like&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) ?></h2>
        <br>
        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php foreach ( $postProds as $postProd ) : ?>

                <?php
                    // $post_object = get_post( $upsell->get_id() );
                    setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $postProd );
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </section>

<?php
}
```

It should end on line 69(ish) before "wp_reset_postdata();". Make sure you replace what is between those lines with the code above, not just add it.

**KEEP IN MIND:** This code will make it so any manual upsells you have set up will not show on the single product page. Instead it pulls 5 random products from the first category in the current product's terms array. If there are less than 5 products in that category, it will display all of them.

Make sure to copy up-sells.php into your child theme directory before editing it.

This code has been tested on version 3.0.0 and works. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Just modify template /woocommerce/single-product/up-sells.php.

```
$cats = get_the_terms($product->id, 'product_cat');
if (!count($cats)) {
    return;
}
$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'no_found_rows'       => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'             => 'rand',
    'post__not_in'        => array( $product->id ),
    'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cats->term_id
        )
    )
);
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Hi...any chance you can post the whole page? as I've replaced this with what is already there and it's not showing anything.

Comment: If you are replacing original templates located in plugin folder, then it is wrong. You should copy them inside your theme and edit them there. Here is original: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/up-sells.php Just replace the obvious part.

Comment: Does not display anything apart from the product...not even if I manually put in some up-sells.

Comment: Paste your code for template in pastebin or smth and share.

Comment: If product doesn't have any upsells then it exits the script. Does your products have upsells? Jesus. Remove line 14. and 16.

Comment: I have removed those lines, I realised after I posted it...but still not showing anything. I've tried it on products with no up-sells and on products where I've added up-sells...Nothing shows!

Comment: Are your products available for sale? Has price, has quantity?

Comment: Yes...products display fine and up-sells display fine if I add them manually, but the whole point is not to add any but show products from same category instead.

Comment: Writing all things that you should check/test will be too long. So I will stop.

Comment: i think the problem is, that $cats->term_id is NULL, so $products->have_posts() is also false

Comment: Hi, what contains $meta_query variable?